# Number of repeating (similar) text units (sentences, paragraphs) in Python or Rapidminer

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, rapidminer

How can I find the number of repeating or very similar sentences or paragraphs in the text document? 
I tried to calculate cosine similarity between the sentences in Rapidminer but with 3000 sentences in each document it is not the best idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at the [FreqDist class](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#module-nltk.probability)?

Comment: @lenz makes a good suggestion. can you show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example please?

Comment: can you add this to the question?

Comment: This question is badly focused. The two problems stated in the title and the first paragraph (counting words and repeated paragraphs) is very straightforward to achieve, but in order for us to help, you need to show your code which doesn't work. The subsequently added problem however – computing similarity of sentences – is a completely different story, with a number of different ways to approach it. It belongs in a separate post, but you need to be more specific: the way it's given now it is too broad for SO.

Comment: Have a look at word2vec, or maybe its siblings sentence2vec and paragraph2vec (I'm not sure if the latter two have Python bindings, but word2vec has).